# How to know if Google Analytics Property is going to exceed 10M Hit Limit? Other than checking on Google Analytics? Any API's given by Google?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using free version of GoogleTagManager and GoogleAnalytics for getting analytics my website. The free version of Google Analytics allows for up to 10 million hits per month, per property as per TOS.

We can check under settings section in GoogleAnalytics account as to what is  the hit count in last day, last 7 days, and last month.

But, since that requires manual intervention that someone has to login to check; Is there a way to get to know what my current limit is for the month? So that if I am closer to breaching the limit we can disable GTM tracing.

Is it different for GTM?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaImTo: Posted the question so to know if any one has programmed this before using GoogleAPI's.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hit limit for GTM.

In Google Analytics, you could use the [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) to get monthly statistics, and then use the [GTM API](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/) to pause the GA tags (which makes this somewhat on-topic).

The relevant metric would be [ga:hit](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_hits). This is not exact (it reports the hit volume of the view rather than the property) but should be "good enough" (as long as your view is not too heavily filtered; since a proper setup includes an unfiltered view in any case this would be a good candidate to get the number).

However you do not need to bother. If you exceed the limits then Google will warn you via email. You then have a few weeks to respond, and introduce sampling or other measures to bring down your hit count. Only if you ignore their warning they will terminate your account.

Comment: The [ReportingAPI](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) has lots of API's. But can't find the API which provides the value of the "Property Hit Volume" for a month. Can you point to a specific API here?

Comment: The reporting api does not report on the property level, but I added a paragraph on how to obtain the value. As I said this is just not a relevant use case - going over the quota occasionally will not cause problems, and if Google thinks you abuse the quota they will tell you.